# AWSで管理するサイトでGmailで送受信しょうとするがドメイン認証ができない

Tags: aws, gmail, google-workspace, amazon-route53

AWSのroute53とec2にてサイト立ち上げて、問題なく稼働しています。
このサイトのドメインでメールのやり取りをしようと思っています。
（SESとWorkMailの運用は難しくて断念しました）

GoogleWorkspaceに申し込み、ドメイン所有を確認するところ躓いています。

Google案内に従って設定を進めています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

手順に従って、Route53のホストゾーンのMXを下記のように設定しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかしながら、未だに下記のようなエラーが発生してしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

変更後、6時間は経過しています。
DNSの更新には時間がかかる場合、48時間程度必要とのことですが、
これまでの経験上からも3時間あれば大丈夫と思っています。

たまたま、今回はすごく時間がかかる事例なのか？
それとも、設定が間違っていて、待ってもNGなのか？

1つめは待つだけなのですが、2つめだとしたら厄介だと思っています。
テストをして結果2日間待つという状態が、繰り返されることになります。

そこで、上記の設定で問題がないのか？
あるいは、このMXの設定以外に影響する部分があるのか？

教えていただけると大変助かります。

気になる点としたら「２ Google MXこれー度を追加する」の確認コードは、小文字で末尾にドットがあります。
しかし「MXレコードの確認」の文字は、大文字で末尾にドットがありません。

現在は「小文字で末尾でドットあり」で登録しています。

よろしくお願いします。

【追記：2023-05-11 10:41】
途中まで SES の設定をしていました、DNSで関連してそうなCNAMEは下記のとおりです。
_d899fb633ee0dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.wmqxbylrnj.acm-validations.aws.
e7esvhkvxojkwly6ffxxxxxxxxx.dkim.amazonses.com
qjzxehjfwbajdr6obzxxxxxxxxxxx.dkim.amazonses.com
whvsqs7jj3llvl7ghfxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkim.amazonses.com

acmは、ssl設定のもので、
dkimは、迷惑メールとして処理されないための設定なので、問題ないかと…
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

【追記 2023-05-11 10:55】
ドメインの追加と管理ドメインの所有権を証明するドメインの所有権を証明する（ドメインホスト別の手順）Amazon Web Services: ご利用のドメインを保護する

によると、[TXT]を設定するとの指示があります。
しかしながら、[TXT]に何を設定するのか、その情報がありません。
「コピーした」の文字にリンクが有るのですが、クリックしても反応なし。
画像は表示されないし、ヘルプが更新されていないのかもしれません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Routen53ですが「レコード名」を`@`でなく空白のままにしたらどうなりますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます！

Comment: できました！！まさかこれが原因だったなんて…

Answer (score 1):

コメントにて、sayuri さんから「レコード名を@ではなく、空白のままにしたら」ということで試してみたところ、
驚くほどあっさり証明が完了しました。（１分もかからなかった）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

調べてみたところ、@ は一般的に「ドメインそのもの」を示すようですが、Route53の場合は @ を「文字」として処理しているみたいです。
（検索しても情報を見つけられなかったのでChatGPTに聞いてみました）

Answer (score 1):

[`@`とはbind（有名なDNSサーバー）におけるゾーン自身を指す記号](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter3.html#the-at-sign)です。この辺りはDNSツール毎に表現が異なるため、ツールに合わせた記述をする必要があります。その上でRoute 53 ホストゾーンにおいては、画面の案内にもあるように「空白のまま」とする必要があります。